# Adding a second query inside the SELECT of a LINQ to Entities query gives Not Recognized Method error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have built a LINQ query for to fill one of my `ViewModel` with data but inside the `.SELECT()` method I tried to add another query to populate one of the VM's properties. When I ran the page I got the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[FFInfo.DAL.Location] Include[Location](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[FFInfo.DAL.Location], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The reason I am using the second query is because `LocationTransitionPoints` does link directly to `Locations` (via `ToLoation` and `FromLocation`) but it does not link directly to `Section` and I don't know how to work my way up to it (LocationTranitionPoints -> Locations -> Section)

I have a felling I am just missing some stupid little thing but can't place my finger on it, any suggestions please?

```
        public ActionResult TransitionPoints()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new GeographyContext())
            {
                var model = db.LocationTransitionPoints
                              .Include("FromLocation")
                              .Include("ToLocation")
                              .Select(ltp => new TransitionPointsVM()
                              {
                                  FromLocation = ltp.FromLocation.Name,
                                  ID = ltp.ID,
                                  SectionTitle = db.Locations.Where(l => l.ID == ltp.ToLocationID).Include("Section").Select(l => l.Section.Title).First(),
                                  ToLocation = ltp.ToLocation.Name,
                                  TransitionPoint = ltp.TransitionPoint
                              }).ToList();

                return View(model);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            return PartialView("LoadError");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't disabled [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazyOffProperty) you should try with the solution that was proposed by @Peter. Otherwise, you can also load the `Section` nav property as part of your query, including it in the path that you pass as parameter in the `Include` method:

```
 using (var db = new GeographyContext())
 {
      var model = db.LocationTransitionPoints
                    .Include("FromLocation")
                    .Include("ToLocation.Section")
                    .Select(ltp => new TransitionPointsVM()
                    {
                      FromLocation = ltp.FromLocation.Name,
                      ID = ltp.ID,
                      SectionTitle = ltp.ToLocation.Section.Title, 
                      ToLocation = ltp.ToLocation.Name,
                      TransitionPoint = ltp.TransitionPoint
                    }).ToList();
           //...
}
```

You can load deeper levels following this pattern:

`Include("FirstLevelNavProp.SecondLevelNavProp...")`

But a better idea is use this another [Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method which is strongly typed:

```
 using (var db = new GeographyContext())
 {
      var model = db.LocationTransitionPoints
                    .Include(ltp=>ltp.FromLocation)
                    .Include(ltp=>ltp.ToLocation.Section)
                    .Select(ltp => new TransitionPointsVM()
                    {
                      FromLocation = ltp.FromLocation.Name,
                      ID = ltp.ID,
                      SectionTitle = ltp.ToLocation.Section.Title, 
                      ToLocation = ltp.ToLocation.Name,
                      TransitionPoint = ltp.TransitionPoint
                    }).ToList();
            //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the Include like your second example and updated the `.Select()` as well and the error is gone and the page is loading. Also thanks for the info on the strongly typed include method, I was not aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just do something like this?

```
var model = db.LocationTransitionPoints
  .Select(ltp => new TransitionPointsVM()
  {
      FromLocation = ltp.FromLocation.Name,
      ID = ltp.ID,
      // get to Section through ToLocation
      SectionTitle = ltp.ToLocation.Section.Title,
      ToLocation = ltp.ToLocation.Name,
      TransitionPoint = ltp.TransitionPoint
  }).ToList();
```

Also, I cut the `.Include()` parts as they're not really necessary since you're projecting into the view model.

Comment: The `.Include()`s are there as I have disabled LazyLoading for performance and resource reasons so I don't think I can step up like you have in your suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried it? The projections should still work with lazy loading disabled.

Comment: No, I did not try it out before I used octavioccl's answer.